# Area chart looks too "spikey"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, d3.js

I have a chart that I've been building, but for some reason, it isn't displaying as an area chart - at least, not smoothly. It's very spikey, and doesn't look very good. My data points are rather strange, but is there any way to have them transition more smoothly?

You can view what the chart looks like at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipKep.jpg

I want it to look more like this chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 (and I copied a large portion of this code to do so, so I'm not sure why it is displaying in this odd way.)

Thanks!

Here is the full code below. For reference, there are data points at every point in time (which is every 3 hours).

```
function InitChart() {

  var lineData = [];
  for (i = 0; i < Math.round(totaltime / interval); i++)
  {
    lineData[i] = {
      "timeinterval": Date.now() - (i * interval * 1000),
      "reactionrate": reactionratebyinterval[i],
      "reach": reachbyinterval[i],
      "engagement": engagementbyinterval[i]
    };
  }

  var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
      margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
      x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
      y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
      xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
      yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5);

  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x2)
      .on("brush", brushed);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var context = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "context")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

  var data = lineData;

  var areareach = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeinterval); })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.reach); })
      .interpolate("monotone");

  var areaengagement = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeinterval); })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.engagement); })
      .interpolate("monotone");

  var areareachbrush = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x2(d.timeinterval); })
      .y0(height2)
      .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.reach); })
      .interpolate("monotone");

  var areaengagementbrush = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x2(d.timeinterval); })
      .y0(height2)
      .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.engagement); })
      .interpolate("monotone");

  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.timeinterval; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.reach; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "areareach")
      .attr("d", areareach);  

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "areaengagement")
      .attr("d", areaengagement);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "areareach")
      .attr("d", areareachbrush);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "areaengagement")
      .attr("d", areaengagementbrush);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);

  function brushed() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.select(".areareach").attr("d", areareach);
    focus.select(".areaengagement").attr("d", areaengagement);
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested it using very smooth data points, and the graph looks just fine. My data points are just really different between time periods - ranging from as high as 1000 to as low as 0. I just want a way for it to transition smoothly, instead of looking so "spikey".

Comment: Read up on the following [interpolate functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate).  Some of these (basis, cardinal and monotone) will smooth your data.  **But** in the end, your data is what it is. Over-smoothing or artificially changing points to look a certain way is misrepresenting your data.

Comment: To confirm, interpolation is the way to go though, for making the data looks "smoother"? If so, make a separate answer and I'll confirm it as answered - that was the thing I really needed answering, so I knew I was heading in the right direction. @Mark

Comment: Make your y range larger, so the variation is less visible. Interpolation will also help.